# How to return large text data from a linked server without using insert exec

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that sits on a linked server that builds articles that I'd like to fetch from the linked server and store the results in a variable.

The articles that get built are often more than 8000 characters so using output parameters isn't going to work.

Is it possible to do this without using insert exec as I want to leave that option open to anyone using the result.

Comment: You can run a normal select against a linked server. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: There is extended logic that goes into building the articles; a simple select would require moving a lot of logic to the select statement that wouldn't be my preferred method of solving this problem.

Comment: Can you use some intermediate table on linked server? Then you could call your sp, which creates and fills new record in that table and returns ID for new record; then you would select record from that table (by ID) and then delete this record.

Comment: I have used the method Arvo suggested in the past to avoid having to use the MSDTC in the past. Getting MSDTC working through firewalls can be more painful than writing around it.